# How to customize error code in custom AuthenticationHandler

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, asp.net-core-authenticationhandler

There is a customized AuthenticationHandler named `CustomAuthenticationHandler` which default error code is 401. But I have to response with different error code and error message in different conditions.

If the request should response 403 in some condition and current solution shows below:

```cs
public class CustomAuthenticationHandler: AuthenticationHandler<MSGraphAuthenticationOptions>
{
    protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        if (xxx) 
        {        
            var response = this.httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response;
            response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden;
            await response.WriteAsync("test");
            return AuthenticateResult.NoResult();
        }
    }
}
```

The error code of the http response is 403 which is expected, but the reqeust still run into `next()` and it would throw error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: StatusCode cannot be set because the response has already started.

at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContext.ThrowResponseAlreadyStartedException(String name)

at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContext.set_StatusCode(Int32 value)

at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContext.Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.IHttpResponseFeature.set_StatusCode(Int32 value)

at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.DefaultHttpResponse.set_StatusCode(Int32 value)

at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.HandleChallengeAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties)

at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.ChallengeAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties)

at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.ChallengeAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme, AuthenticationProperties properties)

at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

at Microsoft.Management.Services.CloudPC.Api.Middlewares.MetricsMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, ILoggerX logger)
```

How can I stop the middlerware flow after `await response.WriteAsync("test");`?

Comment: You can try to check if the 'response has already started' via `response.HasStarted`.

Answer (score 0):

If your authentication fails, you should call `AuthenticateResult.Fail("<your custom message here>");` so the rest of the pipeline doesn't get executed.

Anyway, 403 error message is returned when *Authorization* fails, not in the case of *Authentication* fail, so you might set your authorization policies as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/simple?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Add a authorize attribute is a good solution. But the attribute need to be added in every function in our case, so it is better for us to implement it in authentication. There is no way that 403 can be returned in authentication flow?

Comment: You can set a default authorization policy so no attributes have to be used:

`services.AddAuthorization(options => { options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build(); });` 
This article may be helpful too: https://andrewlock.net/setting-global-authorization-policies-using-the-defaultpolicy-and-the-fallbackpolicy-in-aspnet-core-3/

Comment: `HandleChallengeAsync` helps with rewrite 401 error code. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.authenticationhandler-1.handlechallengeasync?view=aspnetcore-3.1